# Is there any way that we can harden US store bought Cottage Cheese to make Indian Paneer?

Tags: indian-cuisine, paneer

So today I got a box of Daily Chef Cottage Cheese unaware that it will have lumps of cheese flowing in gooey liquid. What I wanted to make was Indian Paneer Curry! Is there any way I can harden it by hanging or something?

Comment: Of interest: http://www.inhouserecipes.com/cottage-cheese-paneer/

Comment: Already read the post..says can't be done so looking for any positive method!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, even if you press it, it will tend to crumble. The way the curds form in small curd cottage cheese forms a skin that makes them tend to fall apart. The same thing can happen in making Indian style paneer if you let the curds boil. (At least, I think it is why it happened!)

Probably your best bet is to drain it then make something like vada or kofte (for malai kofte) out of it, mixing in some maida or cooked potato or besan and kneading it into a dough, then forming it into balls or patties. I think it will still be tasty, even though it isn't what you planned for.

Comment: Did just that..Made yummy Malai Kofta! :)

Comment: glad it worked out. :-)

Answer (score 2):

No you won't get a suitable result. The cottage cheese has already re absorbed a lot of the liquid and you won't be able to get rid of it.

Since you are thinking of hanging it anyway, why don't you make your own? Just follow a cottage cheese recipe but let the curd hang a few hours longer.